# вложенные списки: очистка второго списка влечёт за собой стирание всей вложенной информации и в первом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте, есть такая проблема. При влаживании одного списка в другой, очистка второго списка влечёт за собой стирание всей вложенной информации и в первом. Насколько я понимаю, это следствие передачи лишь ссылки на второй список, а не самих его элементов. Есть какой-нибудь способ обойти эту проблему?

```
List1 = ["123"]
List2 = ["321", "132"]
List1.append (List2)
print (List1) #Результат ['123', ['321', '132']]
List2.clear ()
print (List1) #Результат ['123', []]
```

Задача состоит только в добавлении элементов из List2 в подсписок List1, как получилось до очистки. Но без выкидывания очистки, т.к. нужно будет использовать List2 в новых целях.

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементарно делаем копию списка любым удобным способом:

```
List1 = ["123"]
List2 = ["321", "132"]
List1.append(List2[:])
# Вариант 2: List1.append(List2.copy())
# Вариант 3: List1.append(list(List2))
# Вариант 4, если внутри списка есть ещё списки и прочие изменяемые типы:
# import copy; List1.append(copy.deepcopy(List2))
print(List1) #Результат ['123', ['321', '132']]
List2.clear()
print(List1) #Результат ['123', ['321', '132']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Создать копию списка при добавлении

```
List1.append(list(List2))
```